# Why does sign of $a$ affect the integral of $\mathrm{dx}/ \sqrt { ax^2 + bx + c} $ so much?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c}} dx  $$

It says in book to use one of two formulas but no explanation as to why or how this even derived. Looks interesting as simple sign makes such a difference. Is it anything to with fact that factoring out so you can complete the square means you always have to take its positive as you don't want to $\sqrt{-a} $?

Can anyone help me understand how this comes about? My book just says what to use based on whether $a$ is positive or negative but gives no explanation as to why and I really would like to know how this affects it so much and how formulas given are derived

Comment: Your book doesn't give you any explanation; you don't tell your readers what the book is, or quote the thing it says which you have trouble understanding. Pot, meet kettle.

Comment: Because taking the square root of a negative number will not make much sense for a real area?

Comment: Didn't realise the textbook was so important wasn't particularly complaining about the book . . .was clearly saying I didn't understand why this was being stated in book and how the formula for the integral of such a function was derived so I did state what I was having trouble understanding why the sign of a made such a difference and how the given formula were derived . I asked here as maybe someone could give some insight. _(ed ajf)_

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square does not change the sign of $a$, and the next step after completing the square is to make a variable substitution of the form $u=Ax+B$, which simplifies the integral even more. After that substitution, the integral is reduced to one of the following four:
$$
\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}=\log\big(u+\sqrt{u^2+1}\big)+C\\
\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}=\log\big(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\big)+C\\
\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\arcsin(u)+C\\
\int\frac{du}{|u|} = \frac{|u|}{u}\log|u|.
$$
Notice, however, that the variable substitution $u=Ax+B$ does not change the sign of the quadratic.

By the way, you can resolve the apparent difference between these formulas by using complex numbers. The complex numbers are the real numbers with a special element $i=\sqrt{-1}$ added on. In the complex number system, the first three integral formulas are instances of a single one.

Comment: Shouldn't that last equation be $\int\frac{du}{|u|} = \frac{|u|}{u}\log |u|$? Although I prefer $\text{sgn}(u) \log |u|$.

Comment: Absolutely. I wrote $|u|/u$ because I didn't want to define $\operatorname{sgn}(u)$.